# Highstock Series Compare To Previous Day

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I've implemented the HighStock chart shown at:

http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/compare

This chart shows percent change from the first, or left-most, data point.  I've got some stock analysts telling me this isn't of much use, and that they would rather see percent change from the previous data point, or in other words, if I was looking at "today" on the chart, I would want to see percent change from yesterday.  I've looked over the highstock API and I can't seem to find a way to define the percent change function.  Is there a proper way to have highstock do this or should I use a highcharts line chart to accomplish this?

Comment: What have you tried ? Just a hint, you have to do it by yourself, compare the focused point with the last one inside the tooltip formatter.

Comment: Well it isn't just an issue of the tooltip formatter.  If I only changed the tooltip formatter then the tooltip would show different data than the chart itself, since the chart itself would still be plotting percent change from the first point.

Comment: So, it looks like you're passing the wrong data to highcharts, right ? I think you need to process the chart data on the backend and then pass it to the frontend, where it'll be rendered.

Comment: Thanks for your help Ricardo.  It's not an issue of passing in the wrong data.  I understand I can calculate the percent change myself and use a line based highchart to get a similar effect, but what I am asking is if the highstock chart, shown at the link given in the question has some type of setting available in the highstock API (I have looked, unsuccessfully) so I can alter the percent change function it uses to calculate based off yesterday, as opposed to data point 0, as it seems like it would be a common use case.

Answer (score 5):

I had to do something similar in highcharts before. I wanted to get the actual change from one datapoint to the next.

What I do, is I take a look at the current point (this.x) and I find it's position in the series array. From there, I easily find the index of the previous point (index = a - 1) and do the math. Hope this helps :)

EDIT:

Looked into the stockcharts API and figured it out for that product:

```
tooltip: {
    formatter: function() {
        var s = '<b>'+ Highcharts.dateFormat('%A, %b %e, %Y', this.x) +'</b><br>';

        $.each(this.points, function(i, point) {


            s += '<span style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 1.2em; color: ' + point.point.series.color + ';">' + point.point.series.name + '</span>:<span style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 1.2em;">' + point.y + '</span>' ;
            s += '<span style="font-size: .8em;">';

            var target = this.x;

            index = 0;
            for (var a = 0; a < point.series.points.length; a++) {
               if (point.series.points[a].x == target)
               {
                    index = a - 1;
               }
            }
            var delta = 0;
            var change = 0;
            if (index >= 0)
            {
                delta = this.y - point.series.points[index].y;
                change = (delta  / point.series.points[index].y) * 100;
            }
            s += Math.round(change,2) + '%</span>';


            s +='</span><br>';

        });


        return s;
    }
},
```

And a working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nLjsc/2/

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but in this variation the graph and the tooltip do not show the same data.  Tooltip displays percent change from yesterday, while the y-axis and the lines themselves show percent change from point 0.

Comment: Hmm.. I think then you should only limit the range that you're looking at to the last data point. As you change the scope of what you're looking at the labels on the y-axis change to reflex the % change of the range. Limit it to one, maybe a few, day(s) and you'll see it more accurately reflex that.